# ggplotly() ignores legend and produce different plot with ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, point, ggplotly, geom-point

I try to use ggplotly to run ggplot graph, but the legend label not showing the same things. Why it is? Please help. Thanks
And also any idea to ignore the warning of changing to numeric data, so it doesnt show too many warning when run it through shiny.
Thanks a lot

[image: GGPLOT]

[image: GGPLOTLY]

The code are below

```
structure(list(...1 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
"31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
"42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", 
"53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", 
"64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", 
"75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", 
"86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", 
"97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", 
"107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", 
"116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", 
"125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", 
"134", "135", "136", "137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", 
"143", "144", "145", "146", "147", "148", "149"), indexlist = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 
68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 
84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 
100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 
113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 
126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 
139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149), datainput = c("112069", 
"7377.02", "Unanswered", "675900", "Unanswered", "17323000", 
"1935328.98", "411079", "Unanswered", "38530.29", "96.5", "89268", 
"6380000", "32185.99", "102103", "Unanswered", "Question no match", 
"Unanswered", "Unanswered", "1441914.2080000001", "681325", "89340.307000000001", 
"234", "9278", "9809", "259550", "675900", "Unanswered", "168322", 
"Unanswered", "435708.78", "962.15899999999999", "681325", "81000", 
"38759", "Unanswered", "Question no match", "Unanswered", "195747", 
"Unanswered", "7070890", "10739506", "65430.91", "Unanswered", 
"61900", "Unanswered", "Unanswered", "5130068", "11556", "Unanswered", 
"Unanswered", "102364", "Unanswered", "103451.19", "9756559.5299999993", 
"16520", "644039", "16.187999999999999", "Unanswered", "Unanswered", 
"13154.44", "Question no match", "Question no match", "125131", 
"Unanswered", "Unanswered", "Unanswered", "608470.29", "Question no match", 
"Unanswered", "Unanswered", "Unanswered", "10496.82", "195747", 
"21399", "Unanswered", "214050", "1439.18", "681104", "10587765", 
"11816", "69528", "Unanswered", "26519409", "Question no match", 
"1013315", "17323000", "114016", "117723", "Unanswered", "Question no match", 
"555872.6", "8442.34", "1995000", "Unanswered", "7208", "152495", 
"372366", "132191.5", "21399", "Unanswered", "195747", "3207.89", 
"Unanswered", "77629", "195747", "Question no match", "Unanswered", 
"400", "Unanswered", "555872.6", "3291303", "110296.5", "Unanswered", 
"55715.991999999998", "186011", "Unanswered", "Question no match", 
"Unanswered", "385000", "Unanswered", "142829.75599999999", "125131", 
"Question no match", "20981", "Unanswered", "186011", "9701.8629999999994", 
"Unanswered", "102103", "5138", "4395555.97", "118398.916", "1638.58", 
"2749023", "Unanswered", "9394598", "20960", "17323000", "1232.19", 
"240468", "6963.1", "Unanswered", "348.99400000000003", "2513000", 
"4449880.6100000003", "Unanswered", "Unanswered", "27522854"), 
    verification = c("Yes", "no information", "no answer", "Yes", 
    "no answer", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "no information", "no information", 
    "no information", "no information", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "no answer", "No", "no information", "no answer", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "no information", "no information", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "no answer", "No", "no answer", "no information", 
    "no information", "Yes", "no information", "Yes", "no answer", 
    "No", "no information", "Yes", "no answer", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "no answer", "Yes", "no answer", "no answer", "No", 
    "No", "no answer", "no information", "Yes", "no answer", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "no answer", "no answer", 
    "Yes", "no information", "No", "No", "no information", "no answer", 
    "no answer", "No", "no information", "no answer", "no answer", 
    "no information", "No", "Yes", "No", "no answer", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "no information", "Yes", "no answer", 
    "Yes", "no information", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "no answer", 
    "no information", "No", "no information", "Yes", "no answer", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "no answer", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "no answer", "No", "Yes", "no information", "no answer", 
    "no information", "no answer", "No", "Yes", "No", "no information", 
    "No", "no answer", "no answer", "no information", "no answer", 
    "Yes", "no answer", "Yes", "No", "no information", "Yes", 
    "no answer", "no answer", "No", "no answer", "Yes", "no information", 
    "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "no answer", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "No", "No", "no answer", "no information", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "no answer", "no answer", "Yes")), row.names = c(NA, 
-149L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))->data_a

    p <- data_a%>%
  select(indexlist, datainput, verification) %>%
  mutate_at(c("datainput"), as.numeric)%>%
  drop_na(c("datainput"))%>%
    ggplot(aes(x=1:length(`datainput`), y=`datainput`, label= `indexlist`, color = `verification` == "Yes"))+
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'Verification',breaks = c("TRUE", "FALSE"), values = c("green", "red"), labels = c("Verified", "Non-Verified"))+
    geom_point(size=1.5, alpha = 0.4)+ 
  geom_text(aes(label= ifelse(`datainput` > quantile(`datainput`, 0.975,na.rm = T), `indexlist`,"")),  vjust = "inward", hjust = "inward", size = 2, color = "grey50")+
  theme_minimal()+
  labs(title = "datainput Details",
       x = "",
       y = "")+
  theme(
  axis.text.x = element_text(size = 5.5),
  axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5.5),
  plot.title = element_text(color = "grey40", size = 9, face = "bold"))

ggplotly(p)
```

I have tried scale_manual_fill and colour but it doesnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to keep data cleaning/preparation separate from plotting, see *cleaned* data and plot, now the *ggplot* and *plotly* look the same:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

# prepare the data
plotData <- data_a %>%
  select(indexlist, datainput, verification) %>%
  # remove non-numeric rows before converting
  filter(!grepl("^[^0-9.]+$", datainput)) %>% 
  # prepare data for plotting
  mutate(datainput = as.numeric(datainput),
         x = seq(n()),
         Verification = factor(ifelse(verification == "Yes", "Verified", "Non-Verified"),
                               levels = c("Verified", "Non-Verified")),
         label = ifelse(datainput > quantile(datainput, 0.975, na.rm = TRUE),
                        indexlist, ""))

# then plot with clean data
p <- ggplot(plotData, aes(x = x, y = datainput, 
                          color = Verification, label = label)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("green", "red"))+
  geom_point(size = 1.5, alpha = 0.4) + 
  geom_text(vjust = "inward", hjust = "inward", size = 2, color = "grey50") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "datainput Details", x = "", y = "") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 5.5),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5.5),
        plot.title = element_text(color = "grey40", size = 9, face = "bold"))

# now plotly
ggplotly(p)
```

#### ggplot

[image]

#### plotly

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have tried cleaning your data manipulation process by preparing the data before plotting.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- data_a %>%
  filter(grepl('\\d+', datainput)) %>%
  mutate(datainput = as.numeric(datainput), 
         row = as.numeric(`...1`), 
         verification = ifelse(verification == 'Yes', 'verified', 'Non-Verified')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(row, datainput, color = verification)) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'Verification',
                      values = c("green", "red")) + 
  geom_point(size=1.5, alpha = 0.4)+ 
  geom_text(aes(label= ifelse(datainput > quantile(datainput, 0.975,na.rm = TRUE), indexlist,"")), 
            vjust = -2, hjust = "inward", size = 2, color = "grey50") +
  theme_minimal()+
  labs(title = "datainput Details",
       x = "",
       y = "")+
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 5.5),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5.5),
    plot.title = element_text(color = "grey40", size = 9, face = "bold"))

plotly::ggplotly(p1)
```

[image]